# How to make chart which has both positive and negative value, starts with 0 - x axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was trying to make a chart as shown in the picture. The main problem is I am unable to make this kind of chart with chart.js. Is it possible to make this chart with chart.js?
I have two datasets, first one is for income values, second one is for expenses value. So I have to put income values above 0-X axis and expenses below 0-x axis. And the difference will be shown in that line graph.

What I tried so far is:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            yAxisID: 'y',
            data: ds
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            // backgroundColor: 'blue',
            yAxisID: 'y1',
            data: ds2
        }
    ]
},
options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis'
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            id:"y",
            type:"linear",
            display: true,
            position:"left",
            
        },
        {
            id:"y1",
            type:"linear",
            display: false,
            // position:"left",
            gridLines: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'USD',
                beginAtZero: true,
            }
        }]
    },
} });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend checking official documentation of [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)
Answer to your question yes check [here](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html)

Below simple snippet of that type of chart.You can change input data and other attributes like color of bars, etc.

```js
var MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var barChartData = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
            -10,
            -40,
            80
        ]
    }, {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
            10,
            20,
            30,
        ]
    }]

};

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var value = tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: false
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
              ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                }
              }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: block; width: 1417px; height: 708px;" width="1417" height="708"></canvas>
```

Edit: made changes to the snippet so the y-axis is positive and onHover data is positive.

```
tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var value = tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                }
            }
        },
```

`tooltipItem.yLabel` is value inside tooltip refer to [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

```
 ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                }
              }
```

Here callback function to change y-axis values refer to [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert the negative y-axis ticks and the hover data of the negative values into postive.

Comment: Please check answer I changed fiddle and attached useful links